# How often should you rest? - Running

Tags: running, training, long-distance-running, athletic-performance

I'm an athlete and run around 5 times a week, often 6 miles each time, how often should I have a rest day? Should I cut the 5 times a week down to 3/4 times?

Comment: This is going to be very highly individualized, and nobody can really tell you if its time for you to take a rest day. There are people that can't run more than 3x per week, and there are people that have run at least a mile for thousands of consecutive days.

Comment: @JohnP is right, but there are general guidelines most people would agree with. Like to use a routine easy run as a gauge. If the easy run is hard and cannot be done close to the normal very slow pace then you should be resting instead or cross training. Also there are other clues like higher resting HR in the morning. Anything that hints at overtraining indicates you should have more rest days or cross training days. I find I cant go three weeks hard without following up with a easier week.